# Flow: function call. Callable signature not found in statics of React$Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

I get this error I don't understand in flow:

> Flow: function call. Callable signature not found in statics of React$Component

with this code:

```
export default connect(
  null, { showModal },
)(withRouter(FooterSection));
```

I also get this error:

> Function cannot be called on any member of intersection type
>   intersection

with this code:

```
export default connect(
  (state: State) => ({
    teamId: state.user.user.team,
  }),
  {
    createProject,
  },
)(CreateProjectContent);
```

It happened when I upgraded to `flow@0.53.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problems arose when I updated flow-typed directory as well.

So what I did, I deleted completely `flow-typed/npm` directory and again installed all types with `flow-typed install`.

I handled other errors and flow isn't complaining anymore.